# reactPHP process start blocking timer

Tags: php, asynchronous, timer, reactphp

I have here a reactPHP loop with two timer events:

```
$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$process = new \React\ChildProcess\Process("php wait5seconds.php");

$process->on('exit', function($exitCode, $termSignal) {
    echo "Process Finished".PHP_EOL;
});

$loop->addTimer(2, function($timer) {
    echo "TWO".PHP_EOL;
});

$loop->addTimer(1, function($timer) use ($process) {
    echo "ONE".PHP_EOL;
    $process->start($timer->getLoop());
});

$loop->run();
```

Without the child-process the timers work fine and I get the out put:

```
ONE
TWO
```

But when I start a process in the first timer, the second timer is blocked until the process is finished. I get the output:

```
ONE
Process Finished
TWO
```

Isn't supposed to be asynchronous? the process is sleep(5) so I expect:

```
ONE
TWO
Process Finished
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

Your issue is probably that `php wait5seconds.php` results in an error and thus doesn't run for 5 seconds. If you replace it with `sleep 5`, everything works as expected.

Comment: Are you on linux ? I am on windows

Comment: Yes, you can try `timeout 5` instead on Windows.